# Grails Unit Testing Services - How to flush?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I using Grails V2.4.3 with the HibernateTestMixin. I have a simple unit test for a service as follows:

```
import spock.lang.*
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.gorm.Domain
import grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin
import grails.buildtestdata.mixin.Build

@TestFor(FieldSavingService)
@Domain([Field, SubField])
@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
class FieldSavingServiceSpec extends Specification {

void "Should save Field"() {
    given:
    Field field = new Field(label: "Name").save(flush: true)
    def first = new SubField(caption: "first", sortOrder: 0, field: field).save(flush: true)
    def second = new SubField(caption: "second", sortOrder: 1, field: field).save(flush: true)
    field.addToSubFields(second).addToSubFields(first).save(flush: true, failOnError: true) 

    when:
    service.deleteField()

    then:       
    SubField.findAllByField(field).size() == 0  //test fails
    }
}
```

The service is as follows:

```
class FieldSavingService {
        void deleteField() {
        Field field = Field.findByLabel("Name")
        def  subFields = SubField.findAllByField(field)
        subFields.each{ it.delete()}
        field.delete() //unit test passes if field.delete(flush: true) is called
    }
}
```

The unit test will only pass if I call delete with flush: true in the service. Given that services in Grails are transactional (i.e. domain should be flushed when it returns from the service), how do I get my test to pass without calling flush in my production code? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to explicitly flush current session after delete. Note that you can access current session by using the `hibernateSession` property provided by `HibernateTestMixin` ([source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-datastore-test-support/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/test/mixin/hibernate/HibernateTestMixin.groovy#L81)).

```
void "Should save Field"() {
    given:
    Field field = new Field(label: "Name").save(flush: true)
    def first = new SubField(caption: "first", sortOrder: 0, field: field).save(flush: true)
    def second = new SubField(caption: "second", sortOrder: 1, field: field).save(flush: true)
    field.addToSubFields(second).addToSubFields(first).save(flush: true, failOnError: true) 

    when:
    service.deleteField()
    hibernateSession.flush() // explicitly flush current session

    then:       
    SubField.findAllByField(field).size() == 0  //test fails
}
```